# How to record a reproducible profile in nix (especially from nix-env)?

Tags: nix

So, finally starting to get a stable nix environment that I can basically do all of my development in. Hooray!

Now I want to make it reproducible, as in [yarn.lock](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/yarn-lock/) (for those familiar with npm/yarn in javascript land) or [Pipfile.lock](https://github.com/pypa/pipfile) (very similar for Python).

Basically the idea is that I would have a way to generate a similar lock file whenever I run `nix-env -if my-env.nix`, or after running this command, if that is how it would work. From this lock file, I could then exactly restore my nix profile, down to the exact versions of dependencies and sub-dependencies of the installed profile. This could be checked into git or whatever after testing out new improvements, and so a record of the environment would be maintained.

It seems to me this would be one of the most obvious use cases for Nix, and one of the major advantages over just using Docker (though the two aren't mutually exclusive), so I apologize if I've missed some relevant documentation.

Comment: The user environment doesn't seem like a great tool for this, since it's not that easy to switch between different user environments.  You would probably want to write a shell.nix file to set up your environment with all your favorite dependencies and then run `nix-shell`.

Comment: @DavidGrayson I agree that `nix-shell` may be ideal in many cases, and will probably be gradually using that more. There were two suggestions I had on IRC: 1) use `nix-instantiate` to get the `.drv` file and commit this to git, or 2) Just record the git revision (also using `nix-instantiate`), and use that to checkout a local version of nixpkgs (or some alternative more fancy variant of that, which I may post later once I've tested it). The point of the latter is that if you have nixpkgs at the correct revision, you can reproduce the universe's state.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you're probably looking for is a `shell.nix` file like this:

```
let
  pkgs = import (fetchTarball {
    url = "https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/archive/696c6bed4e8e2d9fd9b956dea7e5d49531e9d13f.tar.gz";
    sha256 = "1v3yrpj542niyxp0h3kffsdjwlrkvj0mg4ljb85d142gyn3sdzd4";
  }) {};
in pkgs.mkShell {
  buildInputs = with pkgs; [
    git
    hello
  ];
}
```

Upon calling `nix-shell` (which by default uses the `shell.nix` file in the current directory), you'll be in an environment with `git` and `hello` from the specific given nixpkgs revision. This can be reproduced among all nix users (okay almost*). I can really recommend using `shell.nix` files for all development.

Alternatively, there's also the lesser known `-r` flag to `nix-env`, which states that

> --remove-all, -r
>
> Remove all previously installed packages first. This is equivalent to running nix-env -e '.*' first, except that everything happens in a single transaction.

You can effectively use it to replace the stateful `~/.nix-profile/manifest.nix`. Create a file `env.nix` containing:

```
let
  pkgs = import <nixpkgs> {};
in {
  inherit (pkgs) git hello;
}
```

Now running `nix-env -ir env.nix` will install exactly `git` and `hello` and remove everything else, so you can reproduce your nix-env installations with this single file. To install additional things: Add it to the file and run the command again. You can also pin nixpkgs to a specific version as in the file above to not care about your `nix-channel` setup (which is also stateful).

**Edit**: It's also possible to get some packages from your channel and some of a specific nixpkgs revision:

```
let
  pkgs = import <nixpkgs> {};
  fixed = import (fetchTarball {
    url = "https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/archive/696c6bed4e8e2d9fd9b956dea7e5d49531e9d13f.tar.gz";
    sha256 = "1v3yrpj542niyxp0h3kffsdjwlrkvj0mg4ljb85d142gyn3sdzd4";
  }) {};
in {
  inherit (pkgs) git;
  inherit (fixed) hello;
}
```

*: The nix config, overlays and your system (Linux/Mac) can still influence this. It's a good idea to use `import <nixpkgs> { config = {}; overlays = []; }` for development to avoid this.

Comment: Excellent, this is great: just adding a few points discussed on IRC: 1) use `nix-prefetch-url --unpack <tarball_url>` to get the sha256 sum, 2) my answer only works for derivations in a channel, and there are some things in the nixpkgs repo that aren't in channels, so your solution is better for reproducibility

Answer (score 0):

After many suggestions from folks on IRC, I was able to put together the following script, which takes a nix expression as its only argument, and copies the derivation file and records the nixpkgs versions locally while installing the specified environment:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -z "$1" ] || [ "${1: -4}" != ".nix" ] || [ ! -f "$1" ]
  then
      echo "No .nix file supplied"
      exit -1
fi

ENV_DRV=$(nix-instantiate "$1")
cp "$ENV_DRV" ./env_backup.drv
chmod u+rw ./env_backup.drv
nix-env --set "$ENV_DRV"


NIXPKGS_VERSION=$(nix-instantiate --eval '<nixpkgs/lib>' -A version)
NIXOS_VERSION=$(nix-instantiate --eval '<nixos/lib>' -A version)

printf "nixpkgs: %s\\nnixos: %s" "$NIXPKGS_VERSION" "${NIXOS_VERSION}" > .nix_versions
```

**Caveat**: your nix expression should have the `nix` package in it, since we are using `nix-env --set`.

I haven't tried using a copied .drv file yet, but it somehow needs to be restored into the nix store; I've mainly included it as a last resort and for debugging. The output into `.nix_versions` should be more helpful, as these contain git commit hashes (after the last ".") that can be used to employ the correct revision of nixpkgs (thanks to infinisil on IRC):

```
pkgs = import "${(import <nixpkgs> {}).fetchFromGitHub { owner = "NixOS"; repo = "nixpkgs"; rev = "<your revision hash>"; sha256 = "<the hash of the output>"; }}" {}
```

To fill in the hash, either supply an incorrect hash to get the correct hash back, or just use the following:  `nix-prefetch-url --unpack github.com/nixos/nixpkgs/archive/<revision>.tar.gz`.

Or, if manually checking out nixpkgs, you can just do e.g.:

```
with import ((builtins.getEnv "HOME") + "/workspace/nixpkgs") { }; # or:
with import "../nixpkgs" { }; # or similar
```

I haven't tested this sort of thing with `nix-shell` yet, but hope to do so soon.